# Python beginner - using constant to open file traceback

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to start using constants in my project and this happened.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aletr\Desktop\Python projects\Restaurant software\r_0.py", line 39, in <module>
    with constants.NAMES_R as f :
  File "C:\Python30\lib\io.py", line 456, in __enter__
    self._checkClosed()
  File "C:\Python30\lib\io.py", line 450, in _checkClosed
    if msg is None else msg)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

I know is because the file it's been closed. But I don't understand how I was using the same code without constant and it would work perfectly.
constants:

```
F_NAMES = 'names.txt'
NAMES_R = open(F_NAMES, 'r+')
NAMES_W = open(F_NAMES, 'w+')
```

script:

```
import constants
with constants.NAMES_R as f :
    f_n = f.read().splitlines()
print("Welcome to NAME.app")
##############
# USER LOGIN #
##############
while True:
    name = input("""
    \n - Insert name to logg in
    \n - ADD to save new user
    \n - LIST to see saved users
    \n - REMOVE to delete a user
    \n - EXIT to finish
    \n - ...""")

    lname = name.lower()

    if lname == "add":
        n_input = input("Name:")
        with open('names.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(n_input + '\n')

    elif lname == "list":
        with constants.NAMES_R as f :
            print(f.read().splitlines())
            f.close()

    elif name in f_n:
        print("Logged as", name.upper())
        user = name
        input('Welcome, press enter to continue \n')
        break

    elif lname == 'remove':
        remove = input("Insert user name to remove \n ...")
        with constants.NAMES_R as f :
            lines = f.readlines()
            lines = [line for line in lines if remove not in line]
        with constants.NAMES_W as f :
            f.writelines(lines)

    elif lname == "exit":
        exit()
```

Comment: What is `constants.NAMES_R`?

Comment: @Craig Sorry, edited and constants added.

Comment: You're using the same `constants.NAMES_R` in multiple places. `with` closes the file for you, but then you attempt to use it again later in the next `with` block. File objects don't really make any sense in a script called `constants` anyways. Just open the file each time it's needed instead of opening it once then attempting to use/close it multiple times.

Comment: You could keep it open and use it multiple times, but then you need to get rid of the `with` blocks. The entire purpose of `with` here is to close the file for you.

Comment: @Carcigenicate That's true, for me it was much better to just use ``with`` without constants but someone reviewing my script said that I was repeating too much and I should start using constants. But at the moment of changing to constants I realise it is not too much repeating due that I always change 'r+','w+', 'a', etc.. . Anyway thank you very much.

Comment: @AlejandroTrinchero Opening the *same file* using both `r+` and `w+` looks weird, given that `w+` truncates.

Comment: @AlejandroTrinchero It makes sense to make the path a constant, but not really the file objects themselves. I'd also put the path constant in the same file that's its used in, unless you have a ton of constants that you want segregated, or, you need the same path in multiple files (although that's just a style preference; not one that has any functional reason).

Comment: @Carcigenicate I don't really get what you call "path".

Comment: @ekhumoro How could I write something on the file without using W+ and truncating? There's another option?

Comment: @AlejandroTrinchero By "path", I mean the string that's the path to the file. In your case here, `F_NAMES`. I would get rid of the two other "constants" in that file for the reasons mentioned above.

Comment: @AlejandroTrinchero And if you want to append to the file, use the mode `a`. `w` will wipe the file before writing to it.

Comment: @AlejandroTrinchero The point is that the file you opened with `r+` will be empty if you immediately open another with `+w` *for the same path*. And there's also no point in opening them both with `+`, since that enables reading and writing *for each file handle*.